# Why use <servlet-mapping> in web.xml(Deployment Descriptor) in jsp/servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/HelloWorld.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Why do we use **url-pattern** inside **servlet-mapping** tag. Why not in **servlet** tag itself.
It's seems just an extra tag to write.
Is it just because servlet/jsp spec writers decided to do so or has it some logical reason behind its existance ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more likely due to the fact that servlets were intended to support multiple protocols, and not just HTTP. URL patterns are specific to HTTP alone, and therefore the mapping of the servlet to HTTP URL patterns is done in a `servlet-mapping` tag, instead of the `servlet` tag which is used for declaring the more generic properties of the servlet.

Comment: Can you please provide any link to bolster your point? Your answer seems most promising.

Comment: The `servlet` tag is annotated in the Servlet specification 2.5 as `The servletType is used to declare a servlet. It contains the declarative data of a servlet.` and the protocol independence is inferred from various bits of articles read over the years, and from the Servlet API documentation for the `GenericServlet` class.

Answer (score 2):

u may try to write another  that also linked to the same servlet,and then u will know that the servlet can have more than one servlet-mapping.

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>    
   <servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>    
   <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>    
   <url-pattern>/HelloWorld.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>    
   <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>    
   <url-pattern>/HelloWorld2.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I thought exactly the same way earlier.But see can't you write it again in servlet tag?The way you are doing it you need to write servlet-mapping tag every time.Look how much bulky the code has become for just two url patterns.What if I have 20.

Comment: I think disscus how to break the roll does not make sense.Many people find that problem,so that there are so many frameworks for web-application to make ur exploitation easier.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Vineet Reynold that servlet-mapping is used to provide support for different protocols available for communication in network. therfore, url-pattern tag let know the servlet the type of protocol ie. HTTP requesting the service.

Comment: Excellent, but you don't need to post a separate answer to say just that, Simply vote up the answer and post your comment if you feel to.BTW thanks a lot for your concern.

Comment: thanks for your concern... ill keep this thing in mind from next time..but i provided little more information in his support.

Answer (score 0):

The limitations and weaknesses of the standard servlet url pattern was a driving factor behind many of the early MVC frameworks (Struts etc). No support for regular expression matching, or even ant-style patterns. No support for url exclusion patterns etc etc.

As to why the specification is the way it is (and still continue to be), I have no idea. The only people who know for sure are the ones who wrote the specs.